# Issue with SQL Data Adapter Search function

Tags: c#, database, winforms, search

This is my code, i'm trying to implement a search function im my application:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

     SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SuperCars where Car like " + textBox1.Text, conn);
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     SDA.Fill(dt);
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;                    
}
```

When i'm trying to search in my database, for example "Bugatti", it said "Invalid column name 'Bugatti'." Maybe it's a simple mistake of mine, but i cannot find it ..

Answer (score 3):

**Problem :** You are not providing the Search parameter properly by ignoring single quotes.

**Solution :** You need to enclose the String types within `single quotes`.

**Suggestion:** your `SELECT` query is open to SQL Injection attacks. You need to use parameterised SQL queries to avoid this.

Parameterised queries helps to pass the parameters with valid types implicitly.

For example you don't need to enclose the string types within single quotes while passing parameters using parameterised queries

**Solution 1:** without using parameterised queries

```
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM SuperCars where Car like '" + textBox1.Text+"'", conn);
```

**Solution 2:** using parameterised queries

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SuperCars where Car like @Car);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car","%"+textBox1.Text+"%");
```

Comment: Take a look at your parameterized query solution again. It is completly wrong. Missing double quote, wrong using of like part..

Comment: @SonerGönül: Thanks for your valuable point. now added code for searching aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Use *[parameterized queries.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)* instead of string concatenations. In this kind of concatenations, you can easily forget some quotes etc..

It is easy to read and prevent [*SQL Injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attakcs.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM SuperCars where Car like '%@car%'");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car", textBox1.Text);
SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, conn);
```

Also use [`using` Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` like;

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\dido\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\CourseProjectCars\CourseProjectCars\DataCars.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
{
  //
}
```

Comment: This all looks nice but now there is an error with this part: SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn); It has some invalid arguments.

Comment: @Cathy Take a look at now. `SqlDataAdapter` doesn't have a constructor takes `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection` as a parameter. I change `cmd` to `cmd.Text` for the right constructor.

Comment: Now the Text part in cmd.Text is underlined and the error is that there is no definition for Text....

Comment: @Cathy I'm so sorry. It is `CommandText` not `Text`. Take a look again.

Comment: @Cathy Did you try your final `SqlCommand` in your server explorer of your database? Does it gets rows when you tried it on your database?

Comment: @Cathy: i think you need to add percentage symbol `%` while passing the parameters in `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` function. try -> `SqlCommand sqlcmd=new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SuperCars where Car like @Car);
    sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Car","%"+textBox1.Text+"%");`